# Got some trouble with canvas in html5

Tags: html

I don't know where my code is broken.
Why my context is not recognized in my script?

I have trouble in this line :
this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

Error message :
Uncaught TypeError: this.canvas.getContext is not a function

I'd like to know why my canvas doses not recognize?
Could you give me an advice?

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.getElementById("canvas_screen"),
    start : function() {
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
  logger : function() {
    alert("log---");  
  }
}
```

Comment: Is canvas_screen a canvas element? And how do you call start function?

Comment: Yeah canvas_screen is a canvas element. I just call the element like this : myGameArea.start(); And I resolved my issue thanks to Kumar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in both Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox browser, but it seems to work fine.

Below is the code I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var myGameArea = {
      canvas : document.getElementById("canvas_screen"),
      start : function() {
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      },
      clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width,  this.canvas.height);
     },
     logger : function() {
     alert("log---");  
    }
  }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas_screen" style="z-index:0;background-color:#000000;  position:fixed;top:20%;left:2%;">
</body>

</html>
```